# Can Minecraft PS4 edition connect to local LAN servers without PlayStation Network?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, psn

**Some context**

I have a home LAN where I connect

- Wifi Router
- Playstation 4
- Playstation 3
- Desktop with Windows 10
- Laptop with Windows 10
- Android Tablet
- Android Phones

I have bought Minecraft for my PS4. My son loves it. We play in multiplayer in the same screen. I don't pay playstation network and would like to avoid it.
I am thinking on *creating a dedicated Minecraft Server* in my desktop PC so I am planning to run a dedicated server there to be able to have the same server for all devices and install mods.

Then I plan to have Minecraft clients in the devices listed above.

**My questions are**

1. Does Minecraft ps4 edition allow you to play in your local LAN?
2. Are clients from different platforms able to play in the same server (PS4, PC, PS3, Android Tablet, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer to #1

You can play on a LAN game on PS4, but you will need **PS Plus**.

## Answer to #2

The clients can play on the same server if they are all of Bedrock Edition. Bedrock Edition is Pocket (Mobile), Xbox One, Playstation 4, Nintendo Switch, and Windows 10 Edition. With that said, if you are setting up a LAN game on your PC you must run the Windows 10 Edition, **not** the Java Edition.

- You have Windows 10 Edition if you bought the game from the Windows Store
- You have Java Edition if you bought the game from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net).

Java edition **cannot** play a LAN game with PlayStation 4. Windows 10 edition **can** play a LAN game with PlayStation 4.

Comment: This is so strange... basically Sony asks me to pay £50/year for PS+ so I can play my local server at home.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears (according to some Reddit threads [#1](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/5khhci/can_i_play_lan_on_minecraft_ps4/), [#2](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSMinecraft/comments/4vobk6/minecraft_on_ps4_without_playstation_plus/), [#3](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSMinecraft/comments/eer95p/ps_needed_to_in_home_lan_multi/), [#4](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/edd0fj/can_i_play_lan_crossplay_games_with_my_pc_without/)), two distinct concepts jump out:

1. Minecraft on the PlayStation 4 doesn't directly support LAN games. They are considered "cross-play" games.
2. As such, what you describe would be considered an "online" game, and therefore you'd need an active PlayStation Plus subscription to join one from a PlayStation 4 console.

A ["bug report" in Mojang's Jira bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-60569) was filed in December 2019 to have developers address this point exactly, but went un-responded to because of a lack of required information on the reporter's part.